# Shopify API return custom message

Tags: ajax, api, shopify

I am using the shopify ajax api to add products to my customers cart, and have a js file with the following code

```
Shopify.onError = function(error) {    


alert('Error: ' + error.message);
},

Shopify.onCartUpdate = function(cart) {
  alert("There are now "+ cart.item_count + " items in the cart.");    
},  

Shopify.onItemAdded = function(line_item) { 
  alert(line_item.title + ' Was aloted to your shopping cart');
},

Shopify.onProduct = function(product) {
  alert('Received everything we ever wanted to know about '+ product.title);
},
```

which i was under the impression would depending on the ajax result return one of the above messages

i am making the call with the following statement

```
<button class="button" onclick="Shopify.addItem(jQuery('#add_item').val(), jQuery('#add_item_qty').val());return false"><i class="foundicon-cart"></i> Add to cart</button>
```

which is working though returning the default messages

Comment: and what is your question?

Comment: why isnt it returning the custom messages I have asked it to

Comment: anyone have any clues as to how to achieve my own messages instead of the default?

Comment: did you include the "api.jquery.js" before including your js file?

Comment: @hjblok yes the api.jquery.js is before my app.'s

Comment: anyone have any further ideas on this?

Comment: could it be a syntax issue `};` instead of `},`? is your script error free?

Comment: @hjblok something so simple that i missed you are correct should be `;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be a syntax issue `},` should be `};`, for example:

```
Shopify.onCartUpdate = function(cart) {
  alert("There are now "+ cart.item_count + " items in the cart.");    
},
```

should be

```
Shopify.onCartUpdate = function(cart) {
  alert("There are now "+ cart.item_count + " items in the cart.");    
};
```